# Merge two comma seperated column in one frame in R

Tags: r, merge, compare

How can i merge two or more column which are seperated with";" in one column using with R? Thanks

Output:

```
X           Y               XY
a;b;c;      x;y;z;          <b>ax</b></br><b>by</b></br><b>cz</b></br>
a2;b2;c2;   x2;y2;z2;       <b>a2x2</b></br><b>b2y2</b></br><b>c2z2</b></br>
a3;b3;c3;   x3;y3;z3;       <b>a3x3</b></br><b>b3y3</b></br><b>c3z3</b></br>
```

Comment: Do you need the `<b>` tags?  If not `do.call(paste0, lapply(df1, function(x) strsplit(x, ";")[[1]]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split the column by `;` and then `paste`

```
data.frame(XY = paste0("<b>", do.call(paste0, 
      lapply(df1, function(x) strsplit(x, ";")[[1]])), "</b></br>"))
#          XY
#1 <b>ax</b></br>
#2 <b>by</b></br>
#3 <b>cz</b></br>
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
map(df2, ~ strsplit(.x, ";")) %>%
               transpose %>%
               map_chr(reduce, ~ 
                 paste("<b>", .x, .y, "</b></br>", sep = "", collapse="")) %>%
               bind_cols(df2, XY = .)
#      X         Y                                               XY
#1    a;b;c;    x;y;z;       <b>ax</b></br><b>by</b></br><b>cz</b></br>
#2 a2;b2;c2; x2;y2;z2; <b>a2x2</b></br><b>b2y2</b></br><b>c2z2</b></br>
#3 a3;b3;c3; x3;y3;z3; <b>a3x3</b></br><b>b3y3</b></br><b>c3z3</b></br>
```

#### data

```
df2 <- structure(list(X = c("a;b;c;", "a2;b2;c2;", "a3;b3;c3;"), Y = c("x;y;z;", 
 "x2;y2;z2;", "x3;y3;z3;")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but output was 1x1 Table. It contains <b> c(NA,NA,NA...)

Comment: Then i get an error like "Error in strsplit(x, ";") : non-character argument "

Comment: @ersan It could be because you have `factor` columns.  Try `strsplit(as.character(x), ";")`

Comment: it is worked very well. is it possible to in one cell. In example output is three raw. I wantto it must be one column.

Comment: @ersan  It is a single column output

Comment: Sorry, İ wanted to say that merged data must be in one cell.
`#1 <b>ax</b></br><b>by</b></br><b>cz</b></br>`

Comment: @ersan In that case, `paste` the column from the output i.e. `paste(out$XY, collapse="")`

Comment: Output

`X Y XY a;b;c; x;y;z; <b>ax</b></br><b>by</b></br><b>cz</b></br> a2;b2;c2; x2;y2;z2; <b>a2x2</b></br><b>b2y2</b></br><b>c2z2</b></br> a3;b3;c3; x3;y3;z3; <b>a3x3</b></br><b>b3y3</b></br><b>c3z3</b></br>`